# Adjusting Timeout duration based on Retry Count

Tags: c#, polly

I'd like to use Polly to do the following: Attempt a request with a very short timeout.  If it fails, retry with a longer timeout.

I see that `Retry` can access `retryCount` like this:

```
Policy
.Handle<SomeExceptionType>()
.Retry(3, (exception, retryCount, context) =>
{
    // do something 
});
```

And I see that `Timeout` can specify an `int` or `TimeSpan`, like this:

```
Policy.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500))
```

I even see that you can pass a function in to the timeout, like this:

```
Policy.Timeout(() => myTimeoutProvider)) // Func<TimeSpan> myTimeoutProvider
```

The `Func` option seems the most promising, but where could it access the retry count?  It's tempting to keep state outside of the policy, but that's dangerous if I ever want to share the policy in a thread safe manner.

Any advice?

Comment: There are examples with the same scenarios documented [here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)

Comment: @Thangadurai I've looked through that documentation.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Polly `Context` to pass state data between different policies involved in an execution.  A unique instance of Polly `Context` flows with every Polly execution, so this is entirely thread-safe.

More detail on this technique [in this blog post](http://www.thepollyproject.org/2017/05/04/putting-the-context-into-polly/).

For example:

```
const string RetryCountKey = "RetryCount";

RetryPolicy retryStoringRetryCount = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .Retry(3, (exception, retryCount, context) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Storing retry count of " + retryCount + " in execution context.");
        context[RetryCountKey] = retryCount;
    });

TimeoutPolicy timeoutBasedOnRetryCount = Policy
    .Timeout(context =>
    {
        int tryCount;
        try
        {
            tryCount = (int) context[RetryCountKey];
        }
        catch
        {
            tryCount = 0; // choose your own default for when it is not set; also applies to first try, before any retries
        }

        int timeoutMs = 25 * (tryCount + 1);
        Console.WriteLine("Obtained retry count of " + tryCount + " from context, thus timeout is " + timeoutMs + " ms.");
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMs);
    });

PolicyWrap policiesTogether = retryStoringRetryCount.Wrap(timeoutBasedOnRetryCount);
```

(*Note*: Of course this ^ can be made more concise. Set out here for maximum clarity.)

Here is a [live dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n0EOuo).

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for. I didn't realize Context could be used this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout

```c#
int retryCount_ = 0;

Func<TimeSpan> myTimeoutProvider = () => 
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(25*retryCount_);

// Configure variable timeout via a func provider.
Policy
    .Timeout(() => myTimeoutProvider)) // Func<TimeSpan> myTimeoutProvider
    .Retry(3, (exception, retryCount, context) =>
    {
        retryCount_ = retryCount;
        // do something 
    })
```

or set the timeout similar to the way shown in:

```c#
Policy
    .Handle<SomeExceptionType>()
    .WaitAndRetry(5, retryAttempt => 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)) 
    );
```

**UPDATE**

You can also hook onto `onTimeoutAsync` callback and keep increasing your local variable that `myTimeoutProvider` relies on.

Comment: The first example is in my original question, and the second is about retry, not timeout.  This does not address my question.

Comment: You can configure the timeoutProvider function to have access to the local scope, such that when it runs you can acces the retryAttempt.. see my updated edit

Comment: Well, I addressed this in my question as well. Keeping external state breaks the thread safety of the policy.